# When admin changes a password for a registered user, I don't want to send a password change email to users

Tags: admin, email, password

I need to change/generate passwords for the registered users, but should not send an email to them regarding this. Admin will tell the password to them later.

these members are registered on the old site, and I just migrated to the new site which is developed in WordPress, so we need these people to log in after new site launch so admin gives the password to them and they can change later.

However, these are unapproved users. Do email for password change goes even for unapproved users? How to prevent sending an email to the users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`'send_password_change_email'`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/send_password_change_email) filter hook.
It is part of the `wp_update_user()` function, fired on admin or on frontend... So I think you can check if the update is done via the admin, then if true, deactivate the email this way...

```
if ( is_admin() )
    add_filter( 'send_password_change_email', '__return_false' );
```

Comment: yeah, will add this functions.php. correct? @ClemC

Comment: @Mann, you can try...

Comment: is there a similar snippet for admin approval,  that means, that means when admin approves user account an email should not be sent. Am using 'Profile Builder' plugin. It sends these mails, approved mails